# Implement the joint-feldman DKG algorithm

Tags: key-distribution

I am looking for a work implementation of joint-feldman DKG or at least some library that can help me in the implementation
Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look up at the [Kyber](https://github.com/dedis/kyber/tree/master/share) library, in the package `share`, there is a the Feldman version as well as the Rabin version.
You can later on use this to make distributed schnorr signatures or TBLS signatures. You can lookup  these types in the `sign` [package](https://github.com/dedis/kyber/tree/master/sign).

PS: I'm one of the authors of these libraries. Happy to help if you have any questions :)